# cv2.VideoCapture freezes on this specific video

Tags: python, opencv

For some reason, it hangs on [this video](http://192.65.213.243/mjpg/video.mjpg):

Here's the code

```
import cv2
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("http://192.65.213.243/mjpg/video.mjpg")

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, img = cap.read()
    current_time_in_milliseconds = "%.5f" % time.time()
    filename="{}.jpg".format(current_time_in_milliseconds)
    cv2.imwrite(filename, img)
```

Any ideas why? Is it something about this video format?
This code works on other mjpg but something about this feed that makes python freeze at cv2.VideoCapture()

I do get this funny error too:

> warning: Error opening file
>   (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:792) warning:
>   http://192.65.213.243/mjpg/video.mjpg
>   (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:793)

Comment: Can you define *"tank"*? Does it always happen at the same place - if so, where? What OS, what versions of everything are you using? What happens if you cut the video in half - do both halves *"tank"* or just one?

Comment: Just how many GB is your file? Is it really a **Minimal, Complete, Verifiable** example?

Comment: Sorry,  tank = fail / hang

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Sorry, i mean that it hangs. And this is a streaming MJPG from IP camera. Not a static local file

Comment: > Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example? 

Yes